# Images are not appearing in emails when using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, backend

I am unable to get images in email, I tried HTTP(s) with images URL but still not get images in email. First I faced issue regarding styling then I put all the styling code in head tag so it works but i only have issue regarding images.

```html
<img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/alianza-taxi/image/upload/v1698326195/omxpca10krtttyhq30pu.svg" alt="not found" />
<img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/alianza-taxi/image/upload/v1698326246/wcckspppvohxvxispmon.svg" alt="not found" />
<img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/alianza-taxi/image/upload/v1698326273/fmhodkvxqpsoqox7kpd6.svg" alt="not found" />
```

Comment: First of all - have you _allowed_ your email client to load external images?

Comment: Yes, I checked the client settings, and it is already allowed.

Comment: So what does "unable to get" actually mean then? Are you seeing "broken image" placeholders? Have you checked the source code of the _received_ email, does everything in there look as it should?

Comment: Does the server receive requests for these images? Does it block them? Does it not find them (e.g., path is wrong or they aren't exposed)? There is not enough information to answer this. All possible answers will be guesses based on other guesses like what your actual stack or configuration is. Or even what the email client does.

Comment: i get broken image icon with not found in emails

Comment: yes, i checked the source code of email found everything in it.